# Match image container width with image width after it is rendered - React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

[image]
I am using [react-image-marker](https://github.com/galexandrade/react-image-marker) which overlays marker on image inside a div.

```
 <ImageMarker
     src={props.asset.url}
     markers={markers}
     onAddMarker={(marker) => setMarkers([...markers, marker])}
     className="object-fit-contain  image-marker__image"
 />
```

The DOM elements are as follows:

```
<div class=“image-marker”>
    <img src=“src” class=“image-marker__image” />
</div>
```

To make vertically long images fit the screen i have added css to contain the image within div

```
.image-marker {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

.image-marker__image {
  object-fit:contain !important;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
```

But now the image is only a subpart of the entire marker area. Due to which marker can be added beyond image bounds, which i do not want.

How do you think i can tackle this. After the image has been loaded, how can i change the width of parent div to make sure they have same size and markers remain in the image bounds. Please specify with code if possible

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding event listeners in useLayoutEffect(). Calculating image size info after it is rendered and adjusting the parent div dimensions accordingly. Initially and also when resize occurs.

If you think you have a better solution. Do specify.

```
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const getRenderedSize = (contains, cWidth, cHeight, width, height, pos) => {
            var oRatio = width / height,
                cRatio = cWidth / cHeight;
            return function () {
                if (contains ? (oRatio > cRatio) : (oRatio < cRatio)) {
                    this.width = cWidth;
                    this.height = cWidth / oRatio;
                } else {
                    this.width = cHeight * oRatio;
                    this.height = cHeight;
                }
                this.left = (cWidth - this.width) * (pos / 100);
                this.right = this.width + this.left;
                return this;
            }.call({});
        }
    
        const getImgSizeInfo = (img) => {
            var pos = window.getComputedStyle(img).getPropertyValue('object-position').split(' ');
            return getRenderedSize(true,
                img.width,
                img.height,
                img.naturalWidth,
                img.naturalHeight,
                parseInt(pos[0]));
        }


        const imgDivs = reactDom.findDOMNode(imageCompRef.current).getElementsByClassName("image-marker__image")
        if (imgDivs) {
            if (imgDivs.length) {
                const thisImg = imgDivs[0]
                thisImg.addEventListener("load", (evt) => {
                    if (evt) {
                        if (evt.target) {
                            if (evt.target.naturalWidth && evt.target.naturalHeight) {
                                let renderedImgSizeInfo = getImgSizeInfo(evt.target)
                                if (renderedImgSizeInfo) {
                                    setOverrideWidth(Math.round(renderedImgSizeInfo.width))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                })
                
            }
        }

        function updateSize() {
            const thisImg = imgDivs[0]
            if (thisImg){
                let renderedImgSizeInfo = getImgSizeInfo(thisImg)
                if (renderedImgSizeInfo) {
                    setOverrideWidth((prev) => {
                        return null
                    })
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        setOverrideWidth((prev) => {
                            return setOverrideWidth(Math.round(renderedImgSizeInfo.width))
                        })
                    }, 390);

                }
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', updateSize);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateSize);
    }, [])
```